# iOS safari overflow-y cut on modal

Tags: css, scroll, modal-dialog, overflow, mobile-safari

After hours of searching the community i haven't been able to solve my problem.

Im currently building a horizontal scroll div with several modals. When i make overflow-x scroll work, it works fine on all devices except iOS Safari. 
This is my code:

**Markup**

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="scroll">
<div id="card">card content</div>
<div id="card">card content</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Style**

```
#parent {
overflow-y: hidden;
}

#scroll {
overflow-x: auto;
min-width: 100vw;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

#card {
width: 222px;
height: 360px;
}
```

when click a card it activates a modal which is supposed to be full width and height. Works fine on Chrome and firefox but it gets cutout on safari mobile.

**References:**
[Screenshot iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCAw0.jpg)    [Screenshot Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNK0R.jpg)